# mypy and "apply" of "Series" does not accept returns of an object of type set[Any]

Tags: python, pandas, mypy, typing

Here is a MRE:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'list1': [1, 2, 3], 'list2': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'list3': [True, False, True]}
series_of_lists: pd.Series = pd.Series(data)

series_of_lists = series_of_lists.apply(lambda x: set(x))
```

The failure I get is the following:

```
6: error: Argument 1 to "apply" of "Series" has incompatible type "Callable[[Any], Set[Any]]"; expected "Callable[..., Union[str, bytes, date, timedelta, datetime64, timedelta64, int, float, complex, Sequence[Any], Mapping[Any, Any]]]"  [arg-type]
6: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Set[Any]", expected "Union[str, bytes, date, timedelta, datetime64, timedelta64, int, float, complex, Sequence[Any], Mapping[Any, Any]]")  [return-value]
```

It seems that mypy is still not satisfied with the lambda function used in the apply method, as it expects the return value to be one of the types listed in the error message.

I'm using `Python 3.11.1`, `mypy 1.1.1`, `pytest-mypy 0.10.3`, `pandas 1.5.3` and `pandas-stubs 1.5.3.230321`.

What is even weirder is that when I print `type(series_of_lists[0])`, I do get `<class 'set'>`.

Comment: `Set[Any]` is **not** a `Sequence[Any]`, of course. `Sequence` is at least subscriptable (`__getitem__`).

Comment: What should I do then, I should be able to apply set to my pandas Series right?

Comment: Since it works in practice

Comment: If `pandas` allows this (your code works correctly), consider reporting a bug [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/) - stubs do not allow action which is allowed at run time. You can wait for it to get fixed or fix the stubs and submit a PR - contributions are certainly welcome. For now just `# type: ignore` this line.

Comment: I reported a bug here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas-stubs/issues/598

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a PR. It's been merged. It should be fixed now.